# How to update $scope.model.value in custom Umbraco data-type before "Save and Publish"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco7

I'm currently working on a custom data-type for Umbraco 7.11, and I would like to update the `$scope.model.value` just prior to the document being saved and published when the user clicks "Save and Publish".

I've searched through the [Umbraco API documentation](https://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/api), for any sort of hook or event that I can subscribe to, to achieve this but have not been able to find anything.

The following is a mock data-type controller in angular, showing what I would like to achieve:

```
angular.module('umbraco')
.controller('MyDataType', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    // I want to update the value of the data-type just before the 
    // document is published, by calling this function
    function onBeforeSaveAndPublish() {

        console.log('Run this code before the document is saved and published')

        // Example of what I would like to do before document is saved and published
        $scope.model.value = new Date().toString()
    }

    // Where to register onBeforeSaveAndPublish() ? Is this possible ?
}])
```

Is this possible, or should I reconsider the design of my data-type?

Comment: Any reason why the value can't just be what you need it to be all the time? To my knowledge there is no "in-between" events to hook in to.

Comment: Thanks for that - the reason for this is that I'm trying to squeeze more data into the data-types value, by using TEXT. Initially I was hoping to use a JSON valueType for this, but for some reason when I attempt to persist complex JSON, the $scope.model.value that I persist comes back as a (sub-)string of the JSON that I attempted to persist. So I was wondering if I could serialize my JSON to a string prior to persisting (ie Save and Publish)